# Python tkinter break function loop

Tags: python, loops, tkinter

```
def buttonWeiterClick(y):
    def skip():
        buttonWeiterClick(1)
    if y == 1:
        x = ampel.getZustand()
        print(x,y)
        anzeigeAktualisieren(x,y)
        ampel.schalten()
        ampel2.schalten()
        fenster.after(3000, skip)
    elif y == 2:
        print("Crashed")
```

**I got a function which calls himself constantly via an .after Statement and I want to know if and how I can end this loop for example via a Button?**

Comment: make the loop to check for a bool variable to be true always. And then when you press a button; make that variable false.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27050492/how-do-you-create-a-tkinter-gui-stop-button-to-break-an-infinite-loop

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39555463/tkinter-how-to-stop-a-loop-with-a-stop-button/39556099

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the result of the `after` function call in some variable `after_id`, and then in your button callback do
    `fenster.after_cancel(after_id)`