# How to end a loop with Tkinter and stop button

Tags: python, tkinter

I am setting up a test bench that needs to have a stop button to end the current program and set everything back to the original state.

I was trying to avoid threading but I do not think it is possible at this point.

*EDIT: It's not a duplicate of the other one, I do not understand how the other code is actually working since i do not have a 'beeper' to test it and understand it. my problem is that I do not know where to enter the if statement so that the stop button is active while the start function is running. when I run the code with the stop if statement, it either doesn't run at all or it runs like it did before with no stop button. Also, even with their method the program still does not stop. What would I need in the def Stop() to actually tell the program to end?

```
import tkinter as tk
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time as time
from time import sleep                                                           


GPIO4 = 4
GPIO17 = 17
GPIO27 = 27
GPIO22 = 22
GPIO23 = 23
GPIO24 = 24

#sets the initial state of the start button#
Start_state = True

#sets GPIOs to GPIO pin numbers#
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

#sets warnings to not show#
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

#sets up GPIOs as outputs#
GPIO.setup(GPIO4, GPIO.OUT)                                                      
GPIO.setup(GPIO17, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(GPIO27, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(GPIO22, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(GPIO23, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(GPIO24, GPIO.OUT)

#sets initial states of the pins#
GPIO.output(GPIO4, False)                                                                
GPIO.output(GPIO17, False)
GPIO.output(GPIO27, False)
GPIO.output(GPIO22, False)
GPIO.output(GPIO23, False)
GPIO.output(GPIO24, False)

#start of main.loop()#
try:

####sets GUI window####
master = tk.Tk()

####name of GUI####
master.title("SOLENOID CONTROL")

####sets size of window (widthxheight)####
master.geometry("650x150")                                                    

####sets initial states of GPIOs to 'off'####
GPIO4_state = False
GPIO17_state = False
GPIO27_state = False
GPIO22_state = False
GPIO23_state = False
GPIO24_state = False                                                          

####defines checkbutton states and relates them to individual GPIOs####
def GPIO4button():                                                            
    global GPIO4_state
    GPIO4_state = not GPIO4_state

def GPIO17button():                                                           
    global GPIO17_state
    GPIO17_state = not GPIO17_state

def GPIO27button():                                                           
    global GPIO27_state
    GPIO27_state = not GPIO27_state

def GPIO22button():                                                           
    global GPIO22_state
    GPIO22_state = not GPIO22_state

def GPIO23button():                                                          
    global GPIO23_state
    GPIO23_state = not GPIO23_state

def GPIO24button():                                                           
    global GPIO24_state
    GPIO24_state = not GPIO24_state

####defines dwell, spray times, and number of repititions (runs) from entry boxes####
def dwell():
    dwell = e1.get()

def spray():
    spray = e2.get()

def runs():
    runs = e3.get()

####defines the start buttons actions####
def Start():

########gets input from entry boxes to be used in while loop#########
    dwell = int(e1.get())
    print('dwell: ' + str(dwell))
    if e1.get() == 0:
        time.sleep(e1.get())
    else:
        pass

    spray = int(e2.get())
    print('spray: ' + str(spray))
    if e2.get() == 0:
        time.sleep(e2.get())
    else:
        pass

    runs = int(e3.get())
    print('runs: ' + str(runs))
    if e3.get() == 0:
        runs = e3.get()
    else:
        pass

########defines the start buttons state and sets i = 0 for the 'runs' counter########
    global Start_state
    i = 0

########when the button is pushed do:########
    if Start_state == True:
############starts loop for 'runs' counter############
        while i < runs:

################prints states of GPIOs and sets state based on checkbutton input, sets dwell and spray time based on entry box input, runs sequentially################
            print('gpio4: ' + str(GPIO4_state))                
            if GPIO4_state == True:
                GPIO.output(GPIO4, True)
                time.sleep(spray)
                GPIO.output(GPIO4, False)
                Start_state == False
                time.sleep(dwell)

            print('gpio17: ' + str(GPIO17_state))                
            if GPIO17_state == True:
                GPIO.output(GPIO17, True)
                time.sleep(spray)
                GPIO.output(GPIO17, False)
                Start_state == False
                time.sleep(dwell)

            print('gpio27: ' + str(GPIO27_state))    
            if GPIO27_state == True:
                GPIO.output(GPIO27, True)
                time.sleep(spray)
                GPIO.output(GPIO27, False)
                Start_state == False
                time.sleep(dwell)

            print('gpio22: ' + str(GPIO22_state))
            if GPIO22_state == True:
                GPIO.output(GPIO22, True)
                time.sleep(spray)
                GPIO.output(GPIO22, False)
                Start_state == False
                time.sleep(dwell)

            print('gpio23: ' + str(GPIO23_state))    
            if GPIO23_state == True:
                GPIO.output(GPIO23, True)
                time.sleep(spray)
                GPIO.output(GPIO23, False)
                Start_state == False
                time.sleep(dwell)

            print('gpio24: ' + str(GPIO24_state))    
            if GPIO24_state == True:
                GPIO.output(GPIO24, True)
                time.sleep(spray)
                GPIO.output(GPIO24, False)
                Start_state == False
                time.sleep(dwell)
            else:
                pass

################prints end of run + run number for east debug################
            print('end: ' + str(i))

################adds 1 to the 'runs' to reach entry box value################
            i += 1

############end of while loop############
        else:
            pass

####creates checkbutton and links it to button command####
####positions checkbutton in GUI window####
checkbutton1 = tk.Checkbutton(master, text="1", command=GPIO4button)
checkbutton1.grid(row=1, column=1)

checkbutton2 = tk.Checkbutton(master, text="2", command=GPIO17button)
checkbutton2.grid(row=1, column=2)

checkbutton3 = tk.Checkbutton(master, text="3", command=GPIO27button)
checkbutton3.grid(row=1, column=3)

checkbutton4 = tk.Checkbutton(master, text="4", command=GPIO22button)
checkbutton4.grid(row=1, column=4)

checkbutton5 = tk.Checkbutton(master, text="5", command=GPIO23button)
checkbutton5.grid(row=1, column=5)

checkbutton6 = tk.Checkbutton(master, text="6", command=GPIO24button)
checkbutton6.grid(row=1, column=6)

####labels checkbutton rows####
tk.Label(master, text="SOLENOIDS").grid(row=1, column=0)

####creates entry boxes and links them to entry variable####
####positions entry boxes in GUI window####
tk.Label(master, text="DWELL TIME").grid(row=6,column=7)
e1 = tk.Entry(master)
e1.grid(row=6, column=8)

tk.Label(master, text="SPRAY TIME").grid(row=7,column=7)
e2 = tk.Entry(master)
e2.grid(row=7, column=8)

tk.Label(master, text="RUNS").grid(row=8,column=7)
e3 = tk.Entry(master)
e3.grid(row=8, column=8)

####creates start, stop, and exit buttons and links them to respective commands####
####starts while loop####
Startbutton = tk.Button(master, text="START", bg="green", command=Start) 
Startbutton.grid(row=10, column=7)

####stops current 'run'####
Stopbutton = tk.Button(master, text="STOP", bg="red", command=Start) 
Stopbutton.grid(row=10, column=8)

####exits GUI window####
Exitbutton = tk.Button(master, text="EXIT", bg="red", command=master.destroy)
Exitbutton.grid(row=10, column=9)

####still no real idea####
master.mainloop()                                                            

#sets all GPIO back to original 'off' state#
finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

The stop button should stop the 'start' function from continuing but it is not active while the start function is running. It will not allow the stop button to be clicked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TKinter - How to stop a loop with a stop button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39555463/tkinter-how-to-stop-a-loop-with-a-stop-button)

Comment: The `while` loop in your `Start()` function prevents tkinter's `mainloop()` from running and freezes the GUI. The possible duplicate @Masoud mentions may help — especially the part about using the universal widget method `after()`.

Comment: It's not a duplicate of the other one, I do not understand how the other code is actually working since i do not have a 'beeper' to test it and understand it. my problem is that I do not know where to enter the if statement so that the stop button is active while the start function is running. when I run the code with the stop if statement, it either doesn't run at all or it runs like it did before with no stop button.